# Convertir consulta de sql a LinQ

Tags: asp.net-core, linq

Buenas  a todos comunidad quiera convertir esta consulta de sql a LinQ
estoy intentado con esta senetencia pero me esta traendo solo los datos de la persona , pero qyo quiero me traiga todas las personas como la consulta , ¿Cómo se podría hacer para que me traiga todas las personas como en la consulta de sql?

```
 personas = (from c in _condominioContext.Mcondominios
                            join d in _condominioContext.Dedificacions
                            on c.MconId equals d.MconId
                            join pre in _condominioContext.Mpredios
                            on d.DediId equals pre.DediId
                            join pro in _condominioContext.Mpropietarios
                            on pre.MpredId equals pro.MpredId
                            join per in _condominioContext.Mpersonas
                            on pro.MpersId equals per.MpersId
                            where pre.MconId.Equals(p.id_cond) && pre.DediId.Equals(p.id_edi) && pre.MpredPiso.Contains(p.piso) && per.MpersNomCompleto.Contains(p.nombre) && d.DediDireccionCompleto.Contains(p.direccion)
                            select new ListaPersonaFil
                            {
                                id_cond = c.MconId,
                                id_pred = pre.MpredId,
                                id_edi = d.DediId,
                                id_per = per.MpersId,
                                id_pro = pro.MpropId,
                                nombre = per.MpersNomCompleto,
                                nombreCondiminio = c.MconNombre,
                                direcEdif = d.DediDireccionCompleto,
                                torre = d.DediTorre,
                                interio = pre.MpredNumeroInt,
                                piso = pre.MpredPiso
                            }).ToList();
```

cosulta sql

```
SELECT * FROM MCONDOMINIOS C
JOIN DEDIFICACION D
ON C.MCON_ID = D.MCON_ID
JOIN MPREDIO PRE
ON D.DEDI_ID = PRE.DEDI_ID
JOIN MPROPIETARIOS PRO
ON PRE.MPRED_ID = PRO.MPRED_ID
RIGHT JOIN MPERSONAS PER
ON PRO.MPERS_ID = PER.MPERS_ID
where PER.MPERS_IDCON='1024'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el select tienes un Right Join a Per y en tu linq esa relación la tienes solo como join  y por eso no te trae todo el personal.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich como podria agregar el rigth join en linq, pensé que se hacia de esa manera

Comment: join per in _condominioContext.Mpersonas on pro.MpersId equals per.MpersId into per2 from  per3 in per2.DefaultIsEmpty()

Comment: en la misma sentencia :( , como seria

Comment: En la la asignación tienes que evaluar si sacas el nombre del per3 o de per en función si uno es nulo. No lo pongo porque no lo puedo probar pero debería funcionar te. Si en la misma sentencia tienes que agregar el into la final de la línea antes del where y agregas el from después de esta. Antes del where viene el from

Comment: Es DefaultIfEmpty. Ah, creo que tienes que intercambiar porque lo antes un left. Empieza mejor por per y has el join a pro

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich on pro.MpersId equals per.MpersId into joined
                            from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty() , pero al agregar esto solo me esta devolviendo el campo , mas no las demas personas

Comment: Intercambia el orden del join . De per hacia pro. ¿No entiendo lo del campo?

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich en per tengo 5 registros y quiero que me regrese los 5 , aunque no sean propietarios , pero solo me esta devolviendo los propietarios , por eso quiero el rigth join para que devuelva todos los registros de la tabla persona

Answer (score 1):

La relación del Per y Pro tiene que ser un *right Join* pero como en linq no hay *Rigth Join* le haces un 'left join'

```
      from per in _condominioContext.Mpersonas
       join  pro in _condominioContext.Mpropietarios
       on per.MpersId equals pro.MpersId into jp
        from p in jp.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

En p tienes todas las personas une este from al from principal como un segundo from.

NOTA: Para no complicarte la vida lleva este LINQ a un List con los datos de la Persona junto a los datos del Propietario. Luego tú Linq sin hacerle el join a personas pero si a Propietarios lo llevas otra lista. Finalmente haces un left join entre las dos lista uniendo por propietario.